# Appending text to span with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I have a progress bar that have 4 steps. See HTML below

```
<ul class="progress-indicator">
<li class="completed"> <span id="signupformstep1" class="bubble"></span></li>
<li class="completed"> <span id="signupformstep2" class="bubble"></span></li>
<li><span id="signupformstep3" class="bubble"></span></li>
<li><span id="signupformstep4" class="bubble"></span></li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery I'm trying to append some text, but it's not doing what I want it to do.

This works but append the same text to all li elements:

```
  $("li").append('hiya');
```

If I try to select the list with the id to append text, it does not show.

```
  $("#signupformstep1").append('hello'); // does not work
```

**EDIT**
I tested with all those markups and they all work, tho the span does not display right but it appends:

```
$("span").html("hello");
$("span").text("hello");
$("span").append("hello");
```

**Span Output**
[image]

```
$("li").html("hello");
$("li").text("hello");
$("li").append("hello");
```

**li Output (desired output)**
[image]

But the minute I use an hashtag, whether I use it on `li` or `span`, it fails. None of the code below runs in my app :

```
$("#signupformstep1").html("hello");
$("#signupformstep1").text("hello");
$("#signupformstep1").append("hello");
```

The desired output would be :

```
<ul class="progress-indicator">
<li class="completed"> <span id="signupformstep1" class="bubble">Step 1</span></li>
<li class="completed"> <span id="signupformstep2" class="bubble">Step 2</span></li>
<li><span id="signupformstep3" class="bubble">Step 3</span></li>
<li><span id="signupformstep4" class="bubble">Step 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qmwd72zb/

Comment: You're not appending to the span, you're appending to the `li`.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes it works in fiddle does not work in my app. And I will edit the question, you are right.

Comment: Hard to help without a [mcve] that fails

Comment: @Brian your question now seems malformatted. The class attribute is now part of the id attribute in the span, with a lone " in the <li> element.

Comment: You have some “ in your <li> that shouldn’t be there

Comment: @charlietfl: well I made the changes and just tried it in my app and it's the same result. It does not work when I use an #. It only works if I use general DOM element names like `li` or `span`

Comment: @FarligOpptreden: Yes sorry I edited too quickly it is fixed now.

Comment: @Brian can you verify that the elements with the IDs you are targeting are on the page at the point of your script executing?

Comment: Works fine with your modified html here https://jsfiddle.net/ssxL91um/ What does `console.log($("#signupformstep1").length)` return? At this point is anyone's guess what is wrong. Code shown works

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you want to see? Do you want <span class”bubble”>hello</span>, and if you write that into your HTML directly does it show? (Sometimes another style can be hiding it)

Comment: @MattKemp: <span class”bubble”>hello</span>, yes this is what I want, yes. And if I hardcode it, it shows fine.

Comment: Also does this involve an external plugin of any kind that adds the id's? One alternative is `$('.progress-indicator li:first span').text('hello')`

Comment: @charlietfl: No nothing else involved here. Just pure css for styling.

Comment: @MattKemp: I've edited with the user view so that you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can't determine why your code isn't working in your app but works in other demos here's an approach that uses [`text(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which internally loops over all bubble class without requiring any `id` and simply relies on indexing to set step number

```js
$('.progress-indicator .bubble').text(i => 'Step ' + (i + 1))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="progress-indicator">
  <li class="completed"> <span id="signupformstep1" class="bubble"></span></li>
  <li class="completed"> <span id="signupformstep2" class="bubble"></span></li>
  <li><span id="signupformstep3" class="bubble"></span></li>
  <li><span id="signupformstep4" class="bubble"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you actually make a post like this but with `li`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean because this matches *"The desired output would be"*

Comment: This is the visual output of your answer https://pasteboard.co/Hn19EDP.png

Comment: Fine but up to you to figure out where text needs to go to work with your css. You provided example output and unless that is updated hard to know where to put it. Adding another span with different common class for the text will make modifying this very simple. note that we can't see your css

Comment: I hear ya. I've edited my question to show you user views and what shows with each code.

Comment: Can see it but impossible to debug css in an image. A new span would help. then you sort out the css

Comment: Can also try `$('.progress-indicator li').html((i,currHtml) => currHtml +  'Step ' + (i + 1))`

Comment: So Charlie, since your last code is successful, I'm talking about this one `$('.progress-indicator li').html((i,currHtml) => currHtml + 'Step ' + (i + 1)) `, if I was to change for other than step 1 text and add something more custom to each step like for instance step 1 would be sign up, step 2 would be checkout etc... How would I achieve that with your code?

Comment: @Brian you can set a `title` attribute to each `.bubble` span and just amend the function passed to the `.html()` call as follows: `(i, currHtml) => currHtml + $(currHtml).attr("title");`

Answer (score 0):

When using `append()` you have to pass it a DOM element to append to the node. So try setting the `text()` instead, along the lines of:

```
$("#signupformstep1 .bubble").text("hello");
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to set text before or after the span inside `<li>` you can specifically add it before or after it:

```
$("signupformstep1 .bubble").before("hello");
$("signupformstep1 .bubble").after("hello");
```

Comment: Although the documentation doesn't say so, `append` will take HTML text.

Comment: First one will wipe out the bubble span

Comment: @charlietfl Right you are. Amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID selectors jQuery and HTML looks like it should work, so is it possible your IDs aren’t all lower case? Or there is something else with the IDs which is out of the ordinary like they are added by another script that runs later.

It should also be noted that text() and html() will replace everything already inside the tag.
So you might want `$(‘#id’).html($(‘#id’).html() + ‘hello’)`

Append adds things after an element it doesn’t add to the existing contents inside it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `$("#signupformstep1").append('hello');` doesn’t work, are you moving the ID to the `<li>` when you do this?

I would steer clear of append() for what you are trying to do here, the way it works can be counter-intuitive.

I think your code is looking ok when you append to the list items, but you’re actually putting the text after the items (out in no-mans land, where they shouldn’t be) and the browser just happens to be rendering them where you want them

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the child selector. If you know which li you want to target do something like:

```
$("#signupformstep1 > .bubble").text("hello");
```

Comment: `val` is for inputs.